# Transferring Xbox360 save file from Series X to PC

Tags: save, archive, xbox, xbox360, xbox-one

I have played an Xbox 360 game (Oblivion) on the Series X and would like to transfer my save files on to the PC. This was possible (and way easier) on the original Xbox 360, and there is lots of documentation on that online.

However, this does not apply to the Series X, as it appears that the save files are stored differently. It seems like the Series X creates a 10MB large "reserved space" file that contains the save slots created in-game.

I could manage to transfer that file to the PC, and [this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPVr8.jpg). I couldn't convert it into a PC save file with the common tools used for original 360 save files, and I couldn't find anything else online on how to open/convert this file.

Is there any way I can open/extract this file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to change the series X file to a 360 format?

Comment: I couldn't find one during my research, but if there is one then it should solve my problem I think

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.